# Where is the Input class in Laravel 4? (or How to find the actual classes of Facades?)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to trace down methods of the Input class in Laravel 4 but I am not able to find the real class.

In `app.php` we have Alias of Input

```
'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
```

But it takes me to file which is just a facade.

```
class Input extends Facade {

    public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return static::$app['request']->input($key, $default);
    }

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'request'; }

}
```

Where is the actual file and how to trace down Facades to Actual Classes in Laravel?

Comment: had you read the comment in that same file, you would have seen `@see \Illuminate\Http\Request`.... __this__

Comment: Yea, just noticed. Thanks!

Comment: @itachi Any idea where exactly it's binding that?

Comment: __from docs:__ Your facade class only needs to implement a single method: `getFacadeAccessor`. It's the getFacadeAccessor method's job to define what to resolve from the container. The Facade base class makes use of the __callStatic()__ magic-method to defer calls from your facade to the resolved object.

So, when you make a facade call like `Cache::get`, Laravel resolves the Cache manager class out of the IoC container and calls the `get` method on the class. In technical terms, Laravel Facades are a convenient syntax for using the Laravel IoC container as a service locator. _its in the docs_

Answer (score 2):

check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades and scroll down to the bottom to see each facade, class name and the IoC binding

Answer (score 2):

`Input` facade is in fact Request: `Illuminate\Http\Request`. You can get all facades classes at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference